# Swift JSON parsing string array

Tags: json, swift

I need to parse following in the Swift.

```
"Address" =     {
    AddressLine = "123 ABC";
};
```

I used

```
if let lineArray = routesDict["Address"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
}
```

which gives ["AddressLine" : "123 ABC"]  I want to get the value 123 ABC.
If i tried lineArray[0] it gives an error

Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'Int'

Comment: It's a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: If i treat it as dictionary  if let lineArray = routesDict["Address"] as? [NSDictionary:AnyObject]  then if never becomes true and it never finds it

Comment: @User382 Swift native dictionary type is 
`[String: Any]`

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113), not an array. Subscript the Dictionary as follows:

```
lineArray["AddressLine"]
```

I suggest you change the variable name to `lineDict` too (as it is a dictionary, not an array)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a dictionary inside another dictionary, you may use the following:

```
let routesDict = ["Address": ["AddressLine":"123 ABC"]]
if let routeAddress = routesDict["Address"] as? [String:Any] {
    print(routeAddress["AddressLine"] ?? "") //123 ABC
}
```

also you should use `Any` (not `AnyObject`), which is more correct in a Swift context:

> The difference between Any and AnyObject is that most Swift native types are structures which doesn't inherit from NSObject so the compiler will have to cast from Swift native types like String, Double, Date and so on to their counterparts when using AnyObject like NSString, NSNumber and NSDate